# How to fix the Internet Explorer Has Stopped Working error in windows8/IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

Getting IE11 error while submitting the form,Issue is when submitting the form IE browser is stopped working,Requirement is, have one form and all input text values getting 'default text' for loading the page itself,so previously we used one jquery plugin.
  But it is not supported in IE11.So I removed jquery default text plugin and adding code manually, here is the code.

```
/*default text related code starts here*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('title') && this.value == ''){
            this.value = $(this).attr('title');
            $(this).addClass('text-label');
        }        
        $(this).focus(function(){
            if(this.value == $(this).attr('title')) {
                this.value = '';
                $(this).removeClass('text-label');
            }
        });

        $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).attr('title') && this.value == '') {           
                this.value = $(this).attr('title');           
            }
        });
    });

    $('select').each(function(){
        if($("select option:selected").val() == '' || $("select option:selected").val() == null){
            $(this).addClass('text-label');
            $(this).change(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('text-label');
            });
        }else{
            $(this).css("color","#000");
        }
        $('option').css("color","#000");  
    });
    /*default text related code ends here*/
```

This code is working fine in IE11 and but not working in windows8/IE11.
  Please help is there any solution.

Here is the screen shot,[image: IE 11 crashing]

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: We figure out the issue causing for default text plugin,so I removed default text plugin and added manually.This code is helping for adding  default to the respective input fields.

Comment: IE 11 crashes when you try to clear too many form fields at once, maybe that's related... https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7036706

Comment: Do you have a live repro URL? If so, I'll investigate for you.